# maven-assembly-plugin fails when appendAssemblyId is set to false

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to build a fat jar with dependencies using maven-assembly-plugin (2.4), JDK 1.8u11, Maven 3.1.1.

I have the plugin configured as following:

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

This gives me the following error when running

```
mvn clean install assembly:single -e


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (default-cli) on project banking-embedded-injector: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single failed: MALFORMED -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (default-cli) on project banking-embedded-injector: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single failed: MALFORMED
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single failed: MALFORMED
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
    at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:58)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:531)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(ZipFile.java:56)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(ZipFile.java:513)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(ZipFile.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoZipFileResourceCollection$1.next(PlexusIoZipFileResourceCollection.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoZipFileResourceCollection$1.next(PlexusIoZipFileResourceCollection.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.AbstractPlexusIoArchiveResourceCollection.getResources(AbstractPlexusIoArchiveResourceCollection.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.proxy.PlexusIoProxyResourceCollection.getResources(PlexusIoProxyResourceCollection.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:468)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.filter.ComponentsXmlArchiverFileFilter.finalizeArchiveCreation(ComponentsXmlArchiverFileFilter.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.runArchiveFinalizers(AbstractArchiver.java:884)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:908)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.createArchive(AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:512)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:186)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:436)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    ... 20 more
```

If appendAssemblyId is set to true, it works fine, but the resulting jar has the "jar-with-dependencies" suffix, which I don't want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you calling maven-assembly outside of the life cycle? Why not just using `mvn clean install` cause you bound it to the life cycle in the package phase?

Comment: This is a submodule of a project, where not all submodules have the plugin attached to the pacakge phase

Comment: But @khmarbaise, that doesn't have anything to do with having appendAssemblyId set to false. I've tested just with mvn clean install and just with mvn assembly:single and it does work. But why?

Comment: Can you make a sample project and put somewhere like on github so i could take a look at it.